# FasterXml(Jackson) and Array deserialization with empty elements

Tags: java, arrays, json, fasterxml

I received the following exception

> com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (',' (code 44)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

when trying to parse array

```
[1,"some text",,,,54]
```

Is it possible to configure object mapper to parse such array with empty elements and put default(null) values in result tree(JsonNode)?

Comment: the problem is not with Jackson, it is that json does not have "empty element" notion (it is only valid in CSV format)

Comment: ok, that is not valid json( But question it was is it possible to parse such string with object mapper. One more i need to parse more complex string like [1, [2,3],,,"text", [2,3,4]]